# build failed for alcatel one touch fire

Tags: build, config, firefox-os, alcatel-ot

I'm trying to build B2G for alcatel one touch fire.
After cloning B2G I ran BRANCH=v2.0 ./config.sh hamachi and then on running ./build.sh I get the following:

Pulling "libOmxWmaDec.so" cp: cannot stat ‘../../../backup-hamachi/system/lib/libOmxWmaDec.so’: No such file or directory Failed to pull libOmxWmvDec.so. Giving up.

> Build failed! <

Build with |./build.sh -j1| for better messages If all else fails, use |rm -rf objdir-gecko| to clobber gecko and |rm -rf out| to clobber everything else.

Answer (score 0):

That is error is because you have not the proper blobs to start building the images. Those blobs are stored in ‘../../../backup-hamachi/’ and they are automatically pulled from your device.

When you try to build the image, the build.sh script automatically backups your system and pulls every lib; it will use them to build your next build.

My suggestions:

1. Test your USB cable, If it is too loose, it may be interrupting the backup.
2. Open an ADB Shell to check if "something" is closing your ADB server meanwhile.
3. Check if that lib exists in your device, use the ADB shell and find it.
4. If it exists, you can always do a backup manually using Busybox: https://wiki.mozilla.org/File:Busybox-b2g.tar.gz
5. If it does not exist, find a proper backup for your Hamachi.
6. Check the following bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1063917